# SQL Server: Replacing all special chars in SQL string

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2005, replace, whitelist

I am working with SQL Server 2005. I need to select all rows from a table that have the same string as a given parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE @param;
```

The only problem is that the title column may contain special chars that have already been replaced by '-' in the compared @param.

Any char in @param except [a-z][A-Z][0-9][-] got replaced by '-', so there is no way to reverse this. (the value comes from a SEO friendly url)

Examples for possible title values and how they should look like:

```
"Adobe Acrobat" -> "Adobe-Acrobat"  
"A+® Certification" -> "A-Certification"
```

I cannot use the SQL REPLACE() function as I need a white-listing mechanism for the chars. There might be very special chars in the title column which I cannot predict.

Regular Expressions would be perfect for this.

I searched for 2 days now but couldnt find an easy and efficient way to implement it in T-SQL.

I could get all rows and do the filtering in the client code, but that doesn't seem to be a very good solution to me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 and above, you can use [SQL CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) functions to use regex efficiently within SQL Server.

There is a download available for a RegEx SQL CLR [here](http://mssqlclr.com/), with source code.

Comment: I stumbled upon this during my search, but read somewhere that it was not recommended for use in production systems. Is that wrong? The Stored Procedure is called from an ASP.Net Page, therefor executed very often and should be as quick as possible.

Comment: @atticae - It might not be the fastest, but it will be faster than doing it in SQL directly... Where did you read it? It could be that this was the case when it first came out, as a new technology.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the source anymore, was on some blog I think, so might've been unreliable information. I will try to get SQL CLR running, if it works fast it should solve my problem.

Comment: Apparently clr is not enabled on the server and I am lacking the necessary privileges to change the option. Will have to wait for our server guy to come back from his holidays. :/ Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're basically using `-` (dash) as a wildcard for any character.  For SQL's `like` statement, the wildcard for any character is `_` (underscore).  So perhaps you could try to replace dash with underscore.  For example:

```
where 'A+® Certification' like replace('A---Certification','-','_')
```

One tiny difference is that underscore matches A-Z0-9 while your dash does not.

Comment: A friend of mine came up with a similiar idea earlier. Only problem is: Multiple dashes are shortened to one dash in the parameter string. (Again for the URLs sake) So I would have to use '%' for wildcard which might return some wrong results on similiar strings. Anyway this might help until I get the clr running. :)